# don't hear any sound,when publishing ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net

I have a website application in ASP.NET. I have two mp3 sounds. Everything works in the computer(in localhost). When I publish the website, I have no error but when press the button, there is no sound. I don't hear anything. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var firstVoice = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
    var secondVoice = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();


    firstVoice.Open(new System.Uri(Server.MapPath("~/") + @"\first.mp3"));

    firstVoice.Play();

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);

    secondVoice.Open(new System.Uri(Server.MapPath("~/") + @"\second.mp3"));

    secondVoice.Play();


    secondVoice.Stop();


}
```

In this code I have two sounds playing simultaneously.

Answer (score 4):

If it plays any sound it plays it on server. Not on client machine. It worked on locahost because it is both server and client.

Comment: could you tell me what changes should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement client side media player. Just Google for "HTML Mediaplayer" or "JavaScript mediaplayer".

For example the basics are described here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp

There're more fancy solutions like http://jplayer.org